# Java Scanner pattern

Tags: java, token

I'm trying to read specific text from file. Text format is

```
@INFO

@DATA
'x', -1, 1 
'y', -1, 1
```

and now I have to tokenize text that is after @DATA tag

```
x
-1
1
y
-1
1
```

For now I got this

```
Scanner in=null;    
try {
    in=new Scanner(file);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    return 1;
}

while(in.hasNext() && !in.next().equals("@DATA"));

while(in.hasNext()) {
    try {
        Object[] obj = new Object[3];
        obj[0] = in.next();
        obj[1] = in.nextDouble();
        obj[2] = in.nextDouble();

    } catch(Exception e) {
        return 2;
    }
}
return 0;
```

it works almost good (getting ''x',') but I have to get word between quotes('). `in.next("'([^']*)'");` doesn't work (java.util.InputMismatchException). How can I tokenize that lines after @DATA tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're going to have to handle the quotes after you get the token back because in [the `Scanner#next(String)` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28java.util.regex.Pattern%29), the regex is used to *test* the next token, not to *determine* the next token.

So, rather than getting the tokenizer to return `x`, you're going to have to expect the tokenizer to return `'x',`, and then make that output work. Fortunately, this isn't hard. A quick and dirty way to do that would look like this:

```
String quotedToken=scanner.next();
quotedToken = quotedToken.replace('\'', ' ');
quotedToken = quotedToken.replace(',', ' ');
quotedToken = quotedToken.trim();
```

It's probably also worth noting that you can get the `Scanner` to handle your commas for you if you get a little clever with your delimiter:

```
`scanner.useDelimiter(",?\\s+");`
```